# Complex selection and checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a complex nested form, without individual classes (can´t change anything there...) and want to check all child checkboxes.

Because of the structure I´ve to do something like the following js:

```
$('.selector input').click(function(event) {
        if(this.checked) { 
            $(this).parents('.row').next('.checkboxselect').css( "background-color", "red" );
         }
        ...
```

That work fine so far, the area I need got the background color.

Now I need to check all checkboxes that can be found in .checkboxselect area, but have no clue how to do that...
Maybe someone had an idea...
Thx a lot!
Best,
Chris

Additional Infos: the form ist build like that (there are a fews blocks like that:

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
       <div>
          INPUT (WHEN THIS IS CHECKED, THE OTHERS SHOULD BE CHECKED TOO
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkboxselect">
    <fieldset>
       <div class="fieldsetct">
          <div class="row">INPUT <- Check me, when the top checkbox is checked</div>
          <div class="row">INPUT <- Check me, when the top checkbox is checked</div>

       </div>     
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: to be clear the checkbox has the class `.checkboxselect` and is the same element you just made red?  HTML would help

Comment: Hi Steve, I add some more infos above!

Comment: $('.selector input') so where is your '.selector' in your html?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example.

1. Handle the change event of the parent checkboxes
2. Find All Checkbox's in the same surrounding `div`.
3. Set their state to the same as the `checkbox` that triggered the event.

```js
$("#sample").on("change", function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.closest(".checkboxselect").find(".fieldsetct>.row>input[type=checkbox]")
    .prop("checked", $this.is(":checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxselect">
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type='checkbox' id='sample' />INPUT (WHEN THIS IS CHECKED, THE OTHERS SHOULD BE CHECKED TOO
    </div>
  </div>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="fieldsetct">
      <div class="row"><input type='checkbox' /></div>
      <div class="row"><input type='checkbox' /></div>

    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just edited my example, had an error there. What worked for me was something like that:

```
$(this).parents('.row').next('.checkboxselect').find('input').prop('checked', true);
```